# How to set button css as half shadow

Tags: html, css, shadow

I need to set css of button like this [website](http://%20https://www.bilboel.dk/), where you can see the `Read more` button with Dark color and half shadow

Please see the following image:

[image: Expected Output]

I tried below code, but I failed:

```
.rmbutton {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background: #504d62 !important;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 13px 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple background, You should fiddle with the values to your liking.

```css
button {
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, red 25%, blue 26%);
}
```

```html
<button>Don't click me</button>
```